# searching data in Gridview c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to c# asp.net. How to search data in a Gridview? My Gridview on page load has all the records from the database. I've been searching on it, most is just searching with an empty GridView. So yeah, mine is not empty.
ERROR: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

```
        String str = "select * from tblEmployee where (Name like '%' + @search + '%')";
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, objsqlconn);
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        objsqlconn.Open();
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Name");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        objsqlconn.Close();
```

Comment: You should paste some code you tried here.....

Comment: @Fel what is your problem ? error? grid view is not visible?

Comment: @Fel *"Ellorin"* can you give use more details about your question? do you have error or something?

Comment: So you have the `DataSet ds`. Can you not search it for the data? Use `DataRow[] drResult = ds.Tables[0].Select("Your Where Clause");`

Comment: The code above is used for direct searching into the db. But what I want is to search data that are loaded in the Gridview from the db. Thank you all.

Comment: @Fel please check your aspx (markup). Do you have `DataSourceID` in the GridView Tag? Need to remove it.

Comment: yes, NP3. I have a datasourceid called SqlDataSource1 but I need for fetching data from the db on page load/

Comment: You can add the code given in the question in `Page_Load` - Either using `IsPostBack` or on every load. You don't need the SQLDataSource again.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the data from grid for searching, you need to store you data some where for using search. That is to store in a ViewState, Session or call DataBase on every search.
Bellow code show data stored in a ViewState, you can acces your data any time by just using GridViewData where you can done search. (if you have very large amount of data first preference is calling data from database on every search.)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GridViewData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}


public DataSet GridViewData
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["GridViewData"] == null)
        {
            String str = "select * from tblEmployee where (Name like '%' + @search + '%')";
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, objsqlconn);
            xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            objsqlconn.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Name");
            objsqlconn.Close();

            ViewState["GridViewData"] = ds;
        }

        return (DataSet)ViewState["GridViewData"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, SHAFEES. Thank you but I'm getting the same error. :()

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SomeThing">
    </asp:GridView> delete this DataSourceID="....." - Kanniyappan

Comment: I need the DataSourceID for loading the data from the db on page load.

Comment: Then delete this one GridView1.DataSource = GridViewData;

Answer (score 1):

@Fel...I think you try to bind data to data grid using sqldatasource from design side as well as code behind side

1) You need to choose one way to bind the grid
2) if you are binding in design side remove the DataSourceID property from grid view design.
 use like this

```
asp:gridview id="grdData" runat="server"
```

instead of

```
asp:gridview id="grdData" runat="server" DataSourceID="Datasource1"
```

Comment: I need it to happen on the onClick event :(

Comment: It's ok.Are you binding data both design side as well code behind?
i am telling to solve this problem "ERROR: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition."

Comment: Removed already. And it's working but  not the way I wanted it to be/ I want to load the data first before searching/ :(

Comment: Load data first in Load Event inside the condition
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
   LoadData()//Binding data
 }

Comment: First Load the data inside the Load Event before page PostBack happen.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectDemo_Asp.et.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Search GridView Record on Button Click By Using C#.Net in Asp.Net</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   
    Search By Title : <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"
        Text="Search" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
            Width="500px" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowFooter="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="author_name" HeaderText="NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="publisher_name" HeaderText="PUB. NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="TITLE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="publication_year" HeaderText="PUB. YEAR" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#66CCFF" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now just check the code on your .cs page.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace ProjectDemo_Asp.et
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\bookstore.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable _objdt = new DataTable();
                _objdt = GetDataFromDataBase("");
                if (_objdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = _objdt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

        /// 
        /// Function for binding retribing the data from database
        /// In this i have used Access DB you can use SQL DB to bind the data
         ///
        public DataTable GetDataFromDataBase(string searchtext)
        {
            DataTable _objdt = new DataTable();
            string querystring = "";
            querystring = "select * from Books";
            if (querystring != "")
            {
                querystring += " where title like '%" + txtsearch.Text + "%';";
            }
            OleDbConnection _objcon = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
            OleDbDataAdapter _objda = new OleDbDataAdapter(querystring, _objcon);
            _objcon.Open();
            _objda.Fill(_objdt);
            return _objdt;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _objdt = new DataTable();
            _objdt = GetDataFromDataBase(txtsearch.Text);
            if (_objdt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = _objdt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```